# MySQL giving incorrect results when trying to find records older than 8 hours

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have the following SQL which is meant to pull a list of songs with a specific type that haven't played in at least 8 hours. `last_played` is a `TIMESTAMP` field, and can also be `NULL` if it hasn't been played yet.

```
SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM spotify_master WHERE type='halloween' AND last_played < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 3600*8)
```

However, it's returning records played as little as 4-5 hours ago.

The last time I ran this query, the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` was `2020-10-01 13:21:19`, and some of the results `last_played` timestamp look like this:

```
2020-10-01 07:37:18
2020-10-01 07:12:47
2020-10-01 09:08:22
```

How can I make my query only return songs which have a `last_played` timestamp at least 8 hours old OR is `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `OR` to also grab the `NULL` values.
Try `- INTERVAL`

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
FROM 
    spotify_master 
WHERE 
    type='halloween' 
    AND (last_played < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 8 HOUR
        OR last_layed IS NULL)
```